# What were the determinant factors in choosing the weight and size of a cricket ball?

Tags: cricket, trivia

What were the determinant factors in restricting the size of a cricket ball to no less than 155.9g and no more than 163g and its circumference to no less than 22.4cm and no more than 22.9cm as stipulated in [law 5 (the ball)?](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-5-the-ball/)

Comment: The precise numbers arise from the historic use of balls with averages of that size and mass, and which are agreed to be reasonable by the experienced. Do you mean to ask why the ball was about that big in the first place, then?